# Can an instance be discarded when one/several feature-values are outside of range?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I'm building a recognizer of antibodies in blod-cells images. It is based on libsvm.  The prototype works well when it comes to recognize an instance which belongs to one of trained classes.
But when I give any image even not containing blod-cells (e.g. Microscope had bad offset/focus), it still suggests one of the classes known by model.

I first considered to implement class "Unknown" but I'm affraid training it with all the noise images would make the model performance worse.

So my idea is to check, if one/several feature(s) of an instance to be recognized is out of value-range and discard it.

Is it a good method? 
If yes, how should the cut-off be selected (e.g. in terms of standard deviations)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In problems with "possible non class samples" the most obvious solution seems to be create a one-class SVM (outlier detection algorithm) in one of two ways:

- Train two one-class SVMs (oner per class) and discard samples marked by both models as "outliers"
- Train one one-class SVM on the whole dataset (instances of both classes) and discard data marked as outlier

Suggested approach with "out of range check" is good as long as there is an obvios threshold value - as you are asking here what would be the best choice - it means that it is **not a good way**. If you cannot (as an expert) figure out it by yourself, it seems much better and safer option to train outlier detection method as suggested before, which will actualy do the same thing, but in the automatic fashion (as it will find rules for discarding "bad data" without training on any "bad images").

Comment: +1: Great! I was not aware of this practical usage of outlier detection. I'll try it. Unfortunately libsvm seems not support outlier detection.

Comment: it **does** support, just set *svm_type* to **2** (it is a code for one class SVM), look at the http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/#nuandone for the list of implemented methods in libsvm

Comment: Thanks! However I'm missing something. The accuracy is always 50%. No matter how I set other parameters, it seems to divide the training set in 50/50 (1 and -1) in recognition. Thus making 2 clusters, not one major cluster and outliers. Could you recommend any parameters?

Comment: There is no such thing as "suggesting parameters". Parameters are data dependant values, and cannot be guessed without the analysis and many trial and errors. If you have a particular problem, ask the separate question, include your code and data and then it will be possible to somehow guide you/help; maybe the problem does not lie in the parameters